# Installing Spacy is failing with Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spacy

Installing Spacy on Windows 10 with pip is failing. Installing any other of a number of modules is working fine for me.

Here is a pastebin containing the error message:

```
pip install -U spacy
```

or

```
python -m pip install spacy
```

output:

https://pastebin.com/Y9np4veN

I have tried this both with and without virtualenv and it is failing in the same manner either way. I have also already tried installing and updating setuptools. I've ensured that I am using Python 3.7 and pip3. There is no other version of python or pip installed on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded to Python 3.6 and was able to successfully install spacy

Answer (score 1):

Using x86-64 ("64-bit") version of Python 3.7 (3.7.4) instead of x86 ("32-bit") one on Windows fixed the issue for me.